# Substitute methods in class without source code

Tags: java

I have some class `A` without source code and this class uses some class `B` with 2 methods like `#get(): int` and set `#set(int value): void` **from standard Java library!**

Can I substitute this 2 methods or all class to change some functionality of this class `A`?

For example, this class `A` uses standard class `B` for saving some information, but I want uses this another container for some operations. It possible?

Comment: Those method signatures are not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some bytecode manipulation libraries like [java-bytecode-asm](/questions/tagged/java-bytecode-asm). However a much simpler approach is to use [aspectj](/questions/tagged/aspectj) and weave classes, either statically or dynamically. AspectJ can even weave standard Java library (`rt.jar`).

Comment: Thanks for information! Maybe you have some examples how to substitute methods using `AspectJ`?

Comment: @vanveber: no example but few tips: search for *around advice* - without calling the wrapped method.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I believe what you are trying to do is
Extend the class and then override the method.

And as kirk woll says, that does not look like java.